# Bijections and disjoint sets by finite summation

Tags: analysis, summation

Suppose $X$ is finite and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a function. Let $g:Y\rightarrow X$ be a bijection. Then $$\sum_{x\in X} f(x) =\sum_{y\in Y} f(g(y))$$ That is what I first want to prove. The second statement: If $X$ and $Y$ are finite and disjoint and $f:X\cup Y\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ a function then:
$$\sum_{z\in X\cup Y} f(z) = \sum_{x\in X} f(x) + \sum_{y\in Y} f(y)$$
These statements are intuitive right, but what must I do to prove this in general and with great accuracy? Can someone help me? Solutions/Hints and remarks are welcome. :)

Comment: Is the second one actually a set question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go back to the defintion of the sum and its compact notation $\Sigma$.

On is given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Formal_definition for indices in $\mathbb{N}$. You can extend it to an other finite set ([that by definition is in bijection with a segment of $\mathbb{N}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set)) using your first equality (that now comes trivially from the definition!).

The other one is just a matter of defining mappings between segements of $\mathbb{N}$ and $X$, $Y$, and $X\cup Y$.

Answer (score 0):

$ \text {First one:  }$

$\text {Because g is a bijection, $\forall$ x $\in X, \exists y \in Y$ s.t. g(y) = x}$

$\text {and $\forall y_1, y_2 \in Y, g(y_1)=g(y_2)\iff y_1=y_2 $}$

$\text {Thus $\sum_{y\in Y}{f(g(y))} = \sum_{x\in X}{f(x)}$}$